# CORS configuration not working

Tags: javascript, https, cors, restful-url

Can any one help me to find correct way to do CORS. I am getting error

### XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://***********/gateway.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7089' is therefore not allowed access

Created below code by referring to previous post related to CORS.
 Java Script Code as below:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {
        xhr = null;
    }

    return xhr;
}

function CallWS(){

    var request = createCORSRequest("POST","https://**************/gateway.com");
    if (request){
        request.onload = function(){
            var res = request.responseText;
            alert(res);
        };
        request.send();
    }
```

Comment: So where's the code which defines the response from `https://***********/gateway.com`? The error message says it is missing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. What have you done to add it?

Comment: This error i got while debugging. variable res will store response

Comment: No. I'm asking about the *server side* code running on `gateway.com` which generates the response. Not the client side code which tries to process it (and which never gets a chance because `gateway.com` doesn't give it permission to)

Comment: I am trying to consume others service providers rest web services..

Comment: Gateway.com is dumy url services i posted here.. don't wanted to share url for some privacy purposes

Comment: You can't get access to data that a third party site will share with your visitors without them giving you permission.

Comment: But I am getting proper response after installing CORS Plugin in chrome.. can't I handle this is java script code?

Comment: No. The data is considered private between the website and the user. The website can use CORS to give the browser permission to share it with another site. The user can install the CORS plugin to give the browser permission to share it with another site. Another site cannot. That would be like `http://hackrs-r-us.com` saying "Dear Browser, it is perfect safe for you give give us your user's data from `http://some-bank.com`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable CORS on the HTTP server when serving the file within you are trying to make the CORS call. when you request the initial page the server should respond with the page and with an Allow access origin header [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) you'll find a better thoroughly explanation

Comment: You mean to say web services provider need enable CORS?

Comment: I mean it's the server who has to enable CORS  to a given domain and to specific HTTP-verbs or you can go straight forward and enable CORS to any domain and any HTTP-verb by registering in all responses the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" but this is not recommended as it has security concerns. check this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Just now i installed CORS Plugin in chrome and tried got response.. if server need to configure then how it works with CORS Plugin?

Comment: I guess you are talking about this [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). 
It works because it acts as a proxy and it adds "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header to every response. It explains it in the plugin description.

Comment: Yes.. is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't think so. CORS is done as this in purpose for security reasons. If it doesn't suit you may hack the request using JSONP but I wouldn't recommend it.